# Need to call header and footer also a main div to call content

Tags: php, html, css

I'm building a site with html and css and i want to make a index.php to   call all the parts for the page. Example Call Header and footer and also when click on nav links replace the content in same page, can i do it with php or what are my options.

Example of my index.php

```
  Get header   < ? php include("header.html"); ? >
   Replace Content  < div class=" MainContent "> < /div>
     Get Footer   < ? php include(" footer.html ") ;?>
```

Comment: Yes you can do it with PHP. Exactly like that (just without the "get/replace")

Comment: Everything is working fine.. i got a index.php calling the header and footer with maincontent, but now im trying to replace the maincontent when i click on a nav btn in the same page..

Comment: When you click on a nav button? Like, you want it to be called asynchronously? So it doesn't refresh the page. Then you'd need to use an ajax call. (a little example in my answer. ;) )

Comment: yes on same page without loading the content again just the maincontent from the nav btn.. where i put ajax code? im trying im trying

Comment: Sorry, I meant like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lrexar5/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditn't tested and didn't put any validation in thiscode but i hope you can get the idea how you can do this. with only index.php file. lmk if any query

header.php
navigation

```
   <html>
<head></head>
<body>
navigation
<a href="mysite?page=home">home </a>
<a href="mysite?page=aboutus">About us </a>
```

page.php

```
page.php
$page_name = $_GET['page'];
<?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path_or_folder_offile/".$page_name.".php" ); ?>
```

footer.php

```
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
 <?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <?php include('page.php'); ?>
    <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: i did what you say but can get pages to load on page.php do i have to include all the pages in page.php? like $home =$_POST ['page'] ; <?php include(#home.' .php') ?> $about =$_POST ['page'] ; <?php include(#about.' .php') ?>

Comment: no you dont have to do anything with page.php , it will get page name from the url. example you clicked on aboutus page (mywebsite.com?page = aboutus)      contactus page(mywebsite.com?page = contactuspage), you have to make your navigation like that , what ever you pass in page paramter on the url , you must create same file example aboutus.php etc etc

Comment: update your code show me what you have done so far. and tell me the error also

Comment: i still cant make it work.. dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: i get this errors 

page.php $page_name = $_POST['page']; 
Warning: include(.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u194839435/public_html/page.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening '.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u194839435/public_html/page.php on line

Comment: it because your path is wrong. please give a proper path of the path where you have stored and created aboutus.php contactus.php etc etc, and sorry it should be GET['page'], i updated my answer please check, it would be good also if you can test how to include files from other folder,

Answer (score 0):

This is my usual page layout for the index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
        <?php if (isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])) { include_once('/pages/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php'); } else { include_once('/pages/index.php'); } ?>
        <?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This uses a GET variable (?page=pageName) to select the page, which I usually use with a redirect rule in Apache.

Alternatively, you can fill the div content from a database. e.g.

```
<div id="content">
    $pageId = $this->getPageId();
    $db = new mysqli_connect('','','','');
    $stmt = db->prepare("SELECT pageContent FROM pages WHERE page_id='$pageId'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($curPageContent);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    echo $curPageContent;
</div>
```

For an ajax call, you can do this:

```
$.get( "/get_page/",
{ page_id: '<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>' })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    });
```

The folder structure I used for this is setup as:

```
root/
    css/
    js/
    pages/
         index.php
         header.php
         footer.php
    index.php
```

Obviously you can use any structure you want, but this may help (although an `assets/` folder is usually good :)

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, i'm gonna give it a try!